# Encontrar el valor con alcalde frecuencia en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

En la actualidad estoy tratando de resolver un algoritmo, no muy complejo, lo que trato es de encontrar el elemento con mayor frecuencia dentro de una lista, la idea es poder imprimir ese elemento, junto con la cantidad de veces que este se repite, además la salida debe separarse por espacios. además de ello, si hay dos elementos que tengan el máximo de apariciones, yo debo imprimir el primero en orden alfabético, yo hice esta solución, sin embargo, no se como hacer que me lo devuelva en orden alfabético, que puedo hacer? en mi solución, creí que estaba haciéndolo de manera alfabética, pero me di cuenta, que solo esta tomando la letra de mayor valor, en este caso la z y no la a de Andrés que seria el que debería imprimirme, gracias por toda la ayuda y la atención prestada.

```
lista = ["andres", "maria", "andres", "maria", "asbdrubal", "zara"]
dic_resultado = {}

for i in lista:
    dic_resultado[i] = lista.count(i)

clave_mayor = max(dic_resultado.keys())

operacion = clave_mayor, dic_resultado.get(clave_mayor)

print(operacion)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para contar las ocurrencias de una nombre usamos la función `Counter` del módulo collections, que toma una lista y devuelve un diccionario. En este caso, el diccionario estará indexado por nombre y contendrá el número de veces que dicho nombre aparece en la lista:

```
from collections import Counter

lista = ["ximena", "maria", "ximena", "maria", "asbdrubal", "zara"]
cuenta = Counter(lista)
```

resulta en

```
cuenta = {'ximena': 2, 'maria': 2, 'asbdrubal': 1, 'zara': 1}
```

Ahora queremos determinar cual es el máximo de veces que se repite una palabra dentro de `cuenta`:

```
maximo = max(cuenta.values())
```

Como puede haber más de una palabra con la misma cuenta, construimos una lista de ellas para poder ordenarlas alfabéticamente:

```
nombres = sorted([nombre for nombre, veces in cuenta.items() if veces == maximo])
```

Esto es más corto que escribir la expresión tradicional equivalente:

```
nombres = []
for nombre, veces in cuenta.items():
    if veces == maximo:
        nombres.append(nombre)
```

y la imprimimos:

```
print(nombres)
```

**Ejemplo**

```
from collections import Counter

lista = ["ximena", "maria", "ximena", "maria", "asbdrubal", "zara"]
cuenta = Counter(lista)
maximo = max(cuenta.values())
nombres = sorted([nombre for nombre, veces in cuenta.items() if veces == maximo])
print(nombres)
```

produce

```
['maria', 'ximena']
```

Comment: Agradezco machismo tu respuesta, una ultima pregunta, si quisiera no solo imprimir el item com mayor frecuencia, sino también la cantidad de su frecuencia, como podría hacerlo? perdón, estoy muy confundido con este ejercicio, aunque entendí muy bien lo que me explicaste.

Comment: @GerardoSuarez. `cuenta` es un diccionario indexado por nombre, y que contiene el número de repeticiones en la lista. Así, `cuenta["maria"]` te devuelve cuantas veces aparece `maria` en la lista. Los nombres vienen en la lista `nombres`.

Comment: Agradezco muchísimos tus respuestas e interés, aprendí muchísimo investigando basado en lo que me enseñaste, eres muy amable brother.